Relation between first three moments of distribution
Consider a random variable $X$ with distribution described by the first three moments:
$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \mu$$
$$\mathbb{E}(X-\mu)^2 = \sigma^2$$
$$\mathbb{E}(X-\mu)^3 = \gamma$$
Is there a nontrivial minimal set of assumptions or family of distributions under which the following relationship between moments holds?
$$\sigma^2 \cdot \mu = \gamma$$

Not really.  Symmetric distributions with at least three moments and $\mu = 0$  would be a subset of all the possibilities, as both $\mu$ and $\gamma$ equal $0$.  But many other distributions do too, with appropriate choices of parameters.

Thanks for the reply. Do you have some examples of cases in which $\mu, \gamma \neq 0$?

The Poisson distribution with mean 1.  Multiple examples are pretty simple to come up with

The Gamma distribution with shape parameter 2 is another...

Thanks. If you write an answer along this line I'll accept it.
